# How to use flutter_background in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-background

I want to make an alarm app that makes my phone vibrate when my backpack is far away from me using RSSI.
But, my app doesn't want to run when my phone is turned off.

I already searched many websites but I couldn't find an article that teaches me to use it other than the official website.